# SyntaxError while attempting to install AppiumLibrary for Robot Framework using pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, appium, robotframework, python-2.x

I have Python 2.7 installed. I am using Robot Framework and the RIDE IDE. I need the `AppiumLibrary`.

I have tried to install it at the CLI as follows:

```
pip install robotframework-appiumlibrary
```

This yields the following error:

[image]

What might be the issue here?

Comment: That's Python 3 syntax (type hints).

Comment: for the installation?

Comment: Yes, installation will run `setup.py`, so you have to have a compatible Python interpreter.

Comment: how can I install it using Python 2.7?

Comment: @Selcuk yep, in fact I just found a link which suggests doing that, and it seems to work. The `AppiumLibrary` is now recognised by my IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a case of broken dependency declaration. `robotframework-appiumlibrary` specifies `Appium-Python-Client>=0.28` as a dependency and although older versions (`>=0.28` and `<1.0`) supports Python 2.x, the later ones do not:

https://pypi.org/project/Appium-Python-Client/

> Since v1.0.0, only Python 3 is supported

So it should be possible to pre-install the latest version that supported Python 2.x to satisfy the dependency:

1. `pip install Appium-Python-Client==0.52`
2. `pip install robotframework-appiumlibrary`